# Html5 input types not working in Firefox and IE up to IE11

Tags: html

I am struggling with html5 input type date, email and other few tags. Which are not working in Firefox and IE up to IE11. Is there any way for use that tags in working condition in both browsers and with all its latest versions. By using Html5 or its crack. I don't want to use any JS library.

Comment: The html5 input types aren't globally supported yet: http://caniuse.com/#search=date

Answer (score 1):

Not all the html5 input types are supported by all browsers. For instance, the email, telephone and URL types have more support than date and time types:

http://caniuse.com/#search=date

http://caniuse.com/#search=telephone

You can use jquery (or other library) alternatives that use date(time) pickers to provide a similar behavior to html5 features. For instance below is an example of jquery datepicker:

```
if ( $('[type="date"]').prop('type') != 'date' ) {
    $('[type="date"]').datepicker();
}
```

You can write your custom html5 alternative plugins and assign them to these fields on browsers not yet supporting the new standards.

Answer (score 0):

You can try webshims, which is available on cdn + only loads the polyfill, if it is needed.

demo version CDN: http://jsfiddle.net/trixta/BMEc9/

```
<!-- cdn for modernizr, if you haven't included it already -->
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/webshim/1.12.4/extras/modernizr-custom.js"></script>
<!-- polyfiller file to detect and load polyfills -->
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/webshim/1.12.4/polyfiller.js"></script>
<script>
  webshims.setOptions('waitReady', false);
  webshims.setOptions('forms-ext', {types: 'date'});
  webshims.polyfill('forms forms-ext');
</script>

<input type="date" />
```